# Creation of additional Authentication at phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, .htaccess, phpmyadmin, .htpasswd

I am following this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-secure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-16-04) in creating phpmyadmin.

The last section is to create secure authentication.

I followed exactly. I have `.htaccess` file inside

```
/usr/share/phpmyadmin/.htaccess
```

I have `.htpasswd` file inside `/etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd`.
When I look inside .htpasswd file, I saw `username:password` line inside the file. Those are credentials I have given.

I used the same user name as in the original credential to phpmyadmin.

But when I login to my phpmyadmin, that additional login window doesn't appear.

Why it doesn't appear?

Thanks

EDIT:
When I checked the error log file at /var/log/apache2/error.log, I have the following messages.

```
[Sun Nov 06 06:25:01.489916 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2087] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Nov 06 06:25:01.489943 2016] [core:notice] [pid 2087] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Sun Nov 06 14:00:18.944623 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 2087] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Nov 06 14:00:19.996901 2016] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 4204] AH00163: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Nov 06 14:00:19.996963 2016] [core:notice] [pid 4204] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

EDIT 2:
`phpmyadmin.conf file inside /etc/dbconfig-common/phpmyadmin.conf` has

```
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>
    Options FollowSymLinks
    DirectoryIndex index.php
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

`/usr/share/phpmyadmin/.htaccess` has

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Files"
AuthUserFile /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

Comment: did you restart the apache server after changing the config file?

Comment: @Dekel y i did.

Comment: did you check the log file for errors?

Comment: @Dekel i checked the file inside /var/log/apache2/error.log. Nothing is significant. I don't see any access failed message. What message should I look for?

Comment: Add the content of the configuration files to the question (otherwise it's hard to help)

Comment: @Dekel It was added as EDIT

Comment: You added the log data, not the configuration (content of .htaccess/phpmyadmin.conf)

Comment: @Dekel I have added into EDIT 2

Comment: `uthType Basic`? :)

Comment: No sorry AuthType

Comment: Check the answer, too much code for a comment.

Comment: Still the same, I have changed already.

Comment: a) Are you using your config file? Maybe redo a `a2enconf phpmyadmin` b) Did you enable `mod_rewrite` (used `a2enmod rewrite`/have `LoadModule rewrite_module` somewhere in your config file)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside .htaccess:

```
Deny from all
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Files"
AuthBasicProvider file
AuthUserFile /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd
Satisfy Any
Require valid-user
```

Comment: Are you sure the file exists in the correct folder on the server? Try only `Deny from all`, it should block everything. If it gives you access your problem is somewhere else :)

Comment: .htaccess is inside /usr/share/phpmyadmin/.htaccess. .htpasswd is inside /etc/phpmyadmin/.htpasswd. Now I changed to Deny from all. But I still can access phpmyadmin login page. Just that additional login page doesn't appear.

Comment: if you have `Deny from all` and you can still access - you have some other problem there...

Comment: Are you sure apache reads the `/etc/dbconfig-common/phpmyadmin.conf` file? if you remove this file (change name to `phpmyadmin.conf.bak`) and restart apache - you still have access to the phpmyadmin?

Comment: Good test. Let me check.

Comment: yes I still have access. I change the file name but still have access.